# gcc warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, warnings

I am making this assignment in my program and I am getting the warning a titled. Here is the code snippet:

`table_name[index] = NULL;`

I could not understand what can be a problem in such a statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NULL is *not* a valid integer, and it is being assigned to an entry of an array made up of presumably `int`s, so the compiler is complaining.

NULL is used as a default pointer value that indicates "nothing" .. if you had a pointer variable and assigned NULL to it, you'd be saying that pointer variable points to "nothing".

Because of this type mismatch, the specific message is *warning* you that you are trying to assign one type (really a pointer value) to another (`int`) without trying to cast it (which is how we sometimes convert one type to another in order to avoid type mismatches).

If you had an array of *pointers* this assignment of NULL would be perfectly ok.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `table_name[index]` is an integer value, not a pointer.  `NULL` is meant to represent pointers.

If `table_name` is declared as `int*`, you could do `table_name = NULL;` without issue, but when setting a value  *at an index*, the compiler is going to expect you to use the same type as the array.

Answer (score 0):

When i try to assign a pointer value into a varriable (always the same data type) then I have the same reaction from the compiler..

example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    int X,Y;
    int *P_1;
    float Z;
    float *P_2;

    X=5;
    Z=3.5;
    P_1=&X;
    printf("\n X = %d, Z = %.2f\n",X,Z);
    printf(" &X = %d\n",&X);
    printf(" *P_1 = %d\n",*P_1);
    printf(" P_1 = %d\n",P_1);  

    Y=X;
    printf(" Y = %d\n",Y);

    X=10;
    Y=P_1;
    fflush(stdin);
    getchar();
    return 0;   
}
```